# How could you show controls for html5 video element in IE11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

IE11 (possibly 10 as well) does not show video controls until you hover over the video itself.

Personally I think is completely useless, especially when you use the poster element as well, because a user cannot know the image is actually a video.

Is there a way to 'force' IE to show the controls, like Chrome does?

The code I use is:

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" poster="/content/files/images/Definition-of-Coaching.png" preload="metadata" controls>
        <source src="/Content/Files/Video/Definition-of-Coaching-SD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="/content/files/video/Definition-of-Coaching-SD.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `control` attribute to the tag? http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-media-controls

Answer (score -3):

You need to add the control tag after declaring the video tag.

As shown in W3 schools:

[W3 Schools -HTML 5 Video](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all)

If you remove the controls attribute, the controls will not appear on the video.

Comment: `controls` is an attribute for the `video` tag.

Comment: Yes, I use the tag correctly.  The code I use is:  

    <video width="100%" height="100%" poster="/content/files/images/Definition-of-Coaching.png" preload="metadata" controls="controls">
    <source src="/Content/Files/Video/Definition-of-Coaching-SD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="/content/files/video/Definition-of-Coaching-SD.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>

Comment: This is pretty old but it is still a problem today. The W3 Schools example posted by Albert Herd in IE11 suffers from the same problem - the controls will fade out after a few seconds.