# HTML5 Video (mp3) disappears if not hovering over IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a  object with an mp3 source.  In Internet Explorer 11, the video player is shown for a few seconds on page load, but then disappears. It reappears when hovering over it.  How do I get it to stay visible all the time?

It is always visible in Firefox.

The html page is auto created and I am stuck with using video instead of audio but I do have control over JS on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>

</head>
<body>
<VIDEO SRC="../media/439.mp3" CONTROLS="controls" WIDTH="400"></VIDEO>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So do we guess what the problem is or do you plan to include the relevant source code to enable  debugging?

Comment: Added the code...

Comment: Do you have any `css` applied to this video element or any javascript events? Also why do you have an **mp3** playing in a video tag.... `mp3` is an audio coding format for digital audio

Comment: No CSS or JS at all.  This is an auto-generated html page.  I only have capability to change js and add css.  That is why i am stuck with the video tag instead of audio.

Comment: Don't you think that would be important to include in your question so people don't waste time offering solutions/answers that aren't available for you to use? Reputation of almost 500, I expected better planning on your question.

Comment: Quote: "html page is auto created and I am stuck with using video instead of audio"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150426/discussion-between-newtojs-and-jpsnow72).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it is more correct and semantic to use the `<audio>` tag (it works the same way and has pretty much the same properties as the `<video>` tag). You should set the `width: 400px` and the `display: inline-block` via css, doing this should work normally, here is an example:

**HTML:**

```
<audio src="../media/439.mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
```

**CSS:**

```
audio{
    width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Edit:** You can use the video tag too, but it's not the right one

Comment: If it does not work and you have some css and js code applied to this player, insert in your question that I fix the answer

Comment: You really should not provide answers to poor questions. There is not enough code provided to know what the issue is. This should really be a  comment, not an answer.

Comment: Or maybe internet explorers default actions on video tags is to hide the controls to give the player a clean display and show those controls upon mouseover/hover.... after all this is a  video element being used and not an audio. "Just a guess"

Comment: @Scott, I'm new here, just wanted to help, but I do not disagree that this question is bad and poorly worded

Comment: @NewToJS, maybe hahaha

Comment: Yes, IE's default action is to hide it which is why i didn't put much code.  I have a completely empty html document and the only thing in it is the video tag.

Comment: Also, unfortunately I don't have control over how the HTML is created, so I am stuck with it being Video instead of an Audio tag.  I considered changing the tag with JS, but I thought that might be overkill.  I thought there had to be a better way with css or something.

Comment: @jpsnow72 it would also appear someone has already asked this question but the only difference is you want to play an audio file rather than a video. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500426/how-could-you-show-controls-for-html5-video-element-in-ie11 see if that becomes of any help but  I would recommend you stick to using an audio tag.

Comment: @jpsnow72 if you have no control over the HTML then how do you expect anyone to tell you how to fix the problem? How do you plan to make changes if you cannot control the HTML? Your question lacks very important information that could lead to a solid solution.

Comment: I can use JS to modify the code or css.  Also, I added the full source.

Comment: @jpsnow72, It would really be a quick fix to solve this, since you have no control over the html, you could by JS get the source of the video tag and dynamically create an audio using that source and then hide the tag from Video and display the audio tag you created

Comment: @LucasHenrique thanks, I think I will use that method.  Just can't believe I can't somehow set it to visible with css.

Comment: @jpsnow72 All right, bro, if it helps you mark it as useful

Answer (score 1):

This is my quick fix... not perfect, but it does the job.

```
$('video').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('src').toLowerCase().indexOf('.mp3') >=0)
    {
        var attrStr = $(this)[0].outerHTML;
        $(this).replaceWith($('<audio '+attrStr + '>' + this.innerHTML + '</audio>'));

    }
});
```